# Redirect users depending upon their role after firebase phone authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic4, firebaseui

I have signed-in users with firebase-UI phone authentication. If the user has signed-in for the first time I am redirecting the user to 'details' page and if the user is old redirecting to 'verification' page. But I am getting different behaviour. The user is firstly redirecting to the right page (verification, or details), but then that page is getting refreshed and then redirecting to the home page and then finally to verification or details page depending upon whether the user is new or old.

I'm also getting this warning

> Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?
>
> warn @ core.js:33461

Here is my code

```
 this.afauth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    let x = this.afauth.auth.currentUser.metadata
    console.log(x)
      if(x.creationTime == x.lastSignInTime) {
        console.log("new user")
       // this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(['details'])
        console.log(this.afauth.auth.currentUser.phoneNumber)
        let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
          state: {
            user: this.afauth.auth.currentUser.phoneNumber
          }
        };
        this.router.navigate(['details'], navigationExtras);
       

      }
      else{
        console.log("old user")
      
        let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
          state: {
            user: this.afauth.auth.currentUser.phoneNumber
          }
        };
        this.router.navigate(['verification'], navigationExtras);
      }
    
  }
  else {
    console.log("something wnt wrong")
  }
})
```

Comment: What do you have in the `verification` and `detail` page that is leading for it to refresh?

Comment: Nothing only signout function and queryparam data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved .In my firebasui config signflow was redirected to home page